# Opening Java URL streams in Windows fails for https urls

Tags: java, windows, https, nullpointerexception

```
//Get the gallery list from the server
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(DOWNLOAD_LIST_URL);
    inputStream = url.openStream();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    Main.gui.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Console output

```
PS Z:\> java -jar .\ImgurWallpaper.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pw.jor.imgurwallpaper.Downloader.getSourceURLs(Downloader.java:78)
    at pw.jor.imgurwallpaper.gui.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:39)
    at pw.jor.imgurwallpaper.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

I'm on the latest Java build 8 update 65 and using Windows 10. This code works fine on my centos box.  Here is the github link to the entire file and project https://github.com/platypusMaximus/ImgurWallpaper/blob/master/src/pw/jor/imgurwallpaper/Downloader.java

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: sorry about that, i was working through a rdp connection that wouldn't allow clipboard sharing

Answer (score 2):

The `NullPointerException` is thrown because static member `gui` of class `Main` is not initialized at this point. Examine your code. You call

```
gui = new GUI();
```

from main method of `Main` class. The constructor `GUI` calls `Downloader.getSourceURLs()` that throws exception. Unfortunately you do not see this exception because your catch block causes `NullPointerException` explained earlier.

So, first of add `e.printStackTrace()` to see the real exception. Then fix it or ask another question here.

But then thick about your design. You are using a lot of static methods and a kind of back references that is not a good practice and in fact caused NPE in your case.

Comment: I'm not seeing why that is a problem.  It works if I try to download a normal non encrypted http link in windows.  And in linux https works as well.

Comment: You get NPE in catch block while trying to log other exception. IMHO it is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was java not trusting the cert authority that I got my ssl key from, in this case StartCom.  This application works fine if I try to download from a website that has a ssl key from a better known authority.

Comment: OH i see the underlying problem now.  I was printing to the gui's text output before it was initialized.  Fixed in this commit https://github.com/platypusMaximus/ImgurWallpaper/commit/a0d1afb77f961293d870c5c8dc4c876d8a128457